# Subring iff congruence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n$ be a square-free integer, and let $A$={$\displaystyle\frac{a+b\sqrt{n}}{2}, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, a\equiv b(mod $ $2$)}.

Prove $A$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ iff $n\equiv 1(mod 4)$.

I tried to apply the subring test, but I am not able to conclude $A$ is closed under product. Also, I can't see why the square-free hypothesis is needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use "\mod" or "\bmod" to get a proper mod operator in mathjax. More generally, if you want some text string in mathjax, use '\text{*string*}". If you don't, mathjax assumes all the letters are variable names and formats them appropriately, giving the ugly result in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a roadmap:

- $A=\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z\theta = \{ u + v \theta : u,v \in \mathbb Z \}$, where $\theta=\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}$
- $A$ is a subring of $\mathbb C$ iff $\theta^2 \in A$

Alternatively, $\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2} \in A$, $\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{2} \in A$ imply $\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2} \cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{2} \in A$.

Comment: Thanks. And how would one prove that the units are the ones that satisfy $|a^2-nb^2|=4$?

Comment: @PedroGarcía, ask a separate question